# Apache Nutch 1.8 Contains no folder named "runtime"

Tags: apache, nutch

I am starting with the Search Engine and i have tried to use Apache nutch as a base for learning. I am watching a tutorial of apache nutch 1.4 (i know its older version ) in which i am asked to go into a folder named runtime but their is no folder in my version. Now my question is , has runtime folder changed with some other folders in newer version ? what i can do to as an alternative with that ? Please help me with that.

Comment: I will say Bad Question.
Which link you are referring? 
Whether you are trying source installation or binary installation is also not mentioned in your question.
If you are looking for configuring Nutch code then please refer this link: http://technicalfudas.blogspot.com/2014/06/how-to-configure-nutch-in-eclipse-for.html

If you are trying to install Nutch from binary folder then you dont have to worry about runtime...

Comment: i was using binary installation. I came to know that in latest versions there is no runtime folder. Direct `bin/nutch crawl` command is executable.Anyways thanks for your reply :)

Comment: If my comments has helped you in some way then you can select "This comments adds something useful to the post"...